# How to prevent widget re-render on ListView scroll

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm building a timeline with posts with images and videos.

When scrolling through the list, the images and posts themselves keep getting re-rendered. This causes sluggishness in the application as dimensions have to be re-calculated + images loaded (from local cache on second load).

How can I prevent the entire post widget from being rebuilt?

Here's the problem illustrated. Please note the loading icon + fade-in animations after scrolling.

[Demo of the problem here (GIF)](https://pasteboard.co/HXVs0Ge.gif)

Here's the code of the `ListView`.

```dart
  ListView.builder(
      physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      cacheExtent: 30,
      addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
      itemCount: _posts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        var post = _posts[index];
        return OBPost(
          post,
          onPostDeleted: _onPostDeleted,
          key: Key(
            post.id.toString(),
          ),
        );
      })
```

I've tried making the `OBPost` widget stateful and adding `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` and `wantKeepAlive => true` but does not change a thing and overall assumed Flutter used the `key` attribute to prevent re-rendering of items.

UPDATE: I've also tried caching the post widgets in a local `List<Widget> _postsWidgets` variable, does not change a thing either.

Comment: any update? I'm wondering the same thing too

Answer (score 1):

Your list looks like it can be infinite scrolling list, so I wouldn't recommend you to cache OBPost widgets. How do you handle image caching? Do you save them to a local filesystem? If yes, then I'd recommend you to also have an in-memory cache of image widgets.

The whole idea behind using builder for ListView is to not create tons of list item widgets, but keep the reasonable minimum of them for memory and performance reasons.

Comment: Hi Roman, yes, I am using https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image which stores them on the local file system. Doing an in-memory cache sounds like a good idea too however reading through Github issues, looks like they might be already cached in memory ( https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16241 ). Do you more about this? Thanks for replying too!

Comment: I checked the code of that library and I'm not sure, if it can use the default behaviour of ImageProvider which should cache images in the memory. I think you may try to debug and see, what happens when you use this library. I also want to say that it's totally fine to have your OBPost objects to be re-created, you just need to find a way to use in-memory cache of images.

Comment: Hi Roman, following up on your thoughts, I've tried using a plain image and its faster loading than using the `cached_network_image`. Finally, I found this library https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_advanced_networkimage which looks like it uses both in-memory and in-storage caching. Works best of everything I've tried.

Comment: Great! I'm glad that I somehow helped you. Thanks for the link to the library, I may need it myself too.